# Zero coupon bond price dynamics under HJM Model

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, stochastic-integrals

I am reading this article: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3330240
and am trying to figure out what is written in the appendix, pages 22 and 23
They wrote:

\begin{align*}
R_j(t) &= \frac{1}{\tau_j}\left[\frac{P(t,T_{j-1})}{P(t,T_{j})}-1\right]
\end{align*}
and they said by applying Itô's lemma we get:

\begin{align*}
dR_j(t) &= \left[R_j(t) + \frac{1}{\tau_j}\right] \int_{T_{j-1}}^{T_{j}} \sigma(t,u) 1_{\{t\leq u\}}du \ dW_j(t)
\end{align*}

given that

\begin{align*}
\frac{dP(t,T)}{P(t,T)} = r(t)dt-\int_t^T \sigma(t,u)1_{\{t\leq u\}}du\ dW(t)
\end{align*}

I tried to write
\begin{align*} \frac{P(t,T_{j-1})}{P(t,T_{j})} & = P(T_{j-1},T_j)\\
dP(T_{j-1},T_j) & = r(T_{j-1})dT_{j-1}-\int_{T_{j-1}}^{T_j} \sigma(T_{j-1},u)du\ dW(T_{j-1})
\end{align*}
But I am not really sure about it, because it does not lead to the result in the article.
Do you have any clue?

Comment: Maybe more suited for this forum : https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer (image below). Maybe it will help someone else. [image]